# Automated docstring and comments spell check

Tags: python, static-analysis, code-analysis, pylint

Consider the following sample code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Test module."""


def test():
    """Tets function"""
    return 10
```

`pylint` gives it 10 of 10, `flake8` doesn't find any warnings:

```
$ pylint test.py 
...
Global evaluation
-----------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10
...
$ flake8 test.py
$
```

But, as you may see, there is a typo in the `test` function's docstring. And, your editor would probably highlight it automagically, for example, here's how Pycharm does it:

[image]

Now I know that there is a relevant spell-checking library called [`PyEnchant`](https://pyenchant.github.io/pyenchant/) that can be used to detect typos.

My end goal is to *automatically detect typos in the project* and make the spell check a part of a continuous build, test and code-quality check run.

Is there a way to achieve that with `pylint`? If not, I would also appreciate any hints on applying `PyEnchant` to docstrings and comments project-wise (in this case, `pylint` or `pyflakes` plugin could be made out of it).

<sup>Please, also, let me know if I'm getting insanely concerned about the code quality.</sup>

Comment: OP literally already referenced that in his question.

Comment: @user3426575 this is exactly why I've mentioned the topic.

Comment: *"Please, also, let me know if I'm getting insanely concerned about the code quality."* - Not in the slightest! :) If I have one pet peeve, it is documentation with spelling and/or grammatical errors. Programmers execute code; they read documentation.  Thus, documentation that leaves you going "What?!" defeats its sole purpose for being there in the first place.

Comment: @iCodez phew, glad we believe and follow the same principles. Thank you.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Pylint includes a [`spell-checker`](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/main/pylint/checkers/spelling.py) since 1.4.0.

Note that, to make the checker work, you need to install [`pyenchant`](http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/) python module and have an [`enchant`](http://www.abisource.com/projects/enchant/) library installed system-wide. On mac, it can be installed via `brew`:

```
$ brew install enchant
```

By default, the `spelling` pylint checker is turned off. You can enable it either in the pylint `rc` configuration file or from the command-line:

```
$ cat test.py
# I am the tyop

$ pylint --disable all --enable spelling --spelling-dict en_US test.py
C:  1, 0: Wrong spelling of a word 'tyop' in a comment:
# I am the tyop
           ^^^^
Did you mean: 'typo' or 'top' or 'tip' or 'topi'? (wrong-spelling-in-comment)
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the instructions! I tried it on real code, and it's kind of difficult: it doesn't know how to ignore code examples, URLs,  and other ReST markup, so variable names are marked as misspellings, etc.

Comment: Yeah, there could a very-very long list of words to ignore (`spelling-ignore-words` setting) which can be eventually difficult to maintain. I'll give it a try on a real project anyway. Thanks.

Comment: For non-mac users `pip install -U pyenchant` should do the job.

Comment: For me this checks everything (variables, classes etc.). I would like it to be done only for docstrings and comments in a py file. I suppose I'm doing something wrong but I'm not sure what. =)

Comment: I seem to be in the opposite situation of @GiampaoloRodolà, where spelling checker _only_ checks docstrings and comments and I am unable to find a checker to check spelling everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows, install enchant with `pip install pyenchant`

Then, to ensure spellchecking, in your `.pylintrc` file, in the section `[SPELLING]`, add `spelling-dict=en_US`.

I also suggest you to add your commonly used acronyms in a `.txt` file and give its path in the option `spelling-private-dict-file=`.

For example:

```
[SPELLING]
# Spelling dictionary name. Available dictionaries: none. To make it working
# install python-enchant package.
spelling-dict=en_US
# A path to a file that contains private dictionary; one word per line.
spelling-private-dict-file=private-dictionary.txt
```

And run with : `pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc yourfile`