# Detecting typos in JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, comments, jshint, eslint, static-code-analysis

In Python world, one of the most widely-used static code analysis tools, `pylint` has a [special check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162315/automated-docstring-and-comments-spell-check), that detects typos in comments and docstrings.

Is there a way to *detect typos in JavaScript code* using static code analysis?

---

To make the question more specific, here is an example code I want to cause a warning:

```
// enter credntials and log in
scope.loginPage.logIn(browser.params.regularUser.login, browser.params.regularUser.password);
```

Here `credntials` is misspelled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a `eslint` plugin built specifically for the task - [`eslint-plugin-spellcheck`](https://github.com/aotaduy/eslint-plugin-spellcheck):

> eslint plugin to spell check words on identifiers, Strings and comments of javascript files.

It is based on the [`hunspell-spellchecker`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hunspell-spellchecker) library that knows how to parse and use [`Hunspell`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunspell) dictionaries of known words:

> Hunspell is a spell checker and morphological analyzer designed for
>   languages with rich morphology and complex word compounding and
>   character encoding, originally designed for the Hungarian language.

Here is what it outputs for the example code provided in the question:

```
$ node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js -c eslint.json showCase.spec.js
25:8   warning  You have a misspelled word: credntials on Comment  spellcheck/spell-checker
```

The plugin is easily customizable and can check in comments, identifiers and strings.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [cspell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cspell). It's a very handy command line tool and finds spelling mistakes in JavaScript, TypeScript, Python, PHP, C#, C++, LaTex, Go, HTML and CSS sources.

**Output for your example**:

```
cspell ./src/code.js
code.js:1:10 - Unknown word (credntials)
```

**./src/code.js**

```
// enter credntials and log in
scope.loginPage.logIn(browser.params.regularUser.login, browser.params.regularUser.password);
```

Comment: Upvoting because they have incredible documentation (http://cspell.org/) and they have an `eslint` plugin that's really easier to configure. Worked right out of the box for me.