# pyenchant / pylint cannot open dictionary files that have unicode paths

Tags: python, windows, pylint, pyenchant, enchant

I want to use pylint on windows with spelling.
I installed it like this `pip install pylint[spelling]`.
And as I went and tried using it like this: `pylint --disable all --enable spelling --spelling-dict en_US .`
I expected it to check the my spelling in my python code like [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27162411/14030123).
it raises errors that it cannot open the files like this:

```
error: C:\Users\╫₧╫⌐╫¬╫₧╫⌐\Documents\pylint example\.venv\Lib\site-packages\enchant\data\mingw64\share\enchant\hunspell\en_US.aff: cannot open
error: C:\Users\╫₧╫⌐╫¬╫₧╫⌐\Documents\pylint example\.venv\Lib\site-packages\enchant\data\mingw64\share\enchant\hunspell\en_US.dic: cannot open
error: C:\Users\╫₧╫⌐╫¬╫₧╫⌐\Documents\pylint example\.venv\Lib\site-packages\enchant\data\mingw64\share\enchant\hunspell\en_US.aff: cannot open
```

I guess it's because my user uses unicode charecters, does anyone knows how to solve this?
Thanks in ahead!

[Edit]
I am not sure if it's a `pylint` problem or a `pyenchant` problem. So I added both to the title. I think it's a `pyenchant` problem.